# Hibernate : generic inheritance with OneToOne relationship

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have the following hibernate entities:

```java
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class MySuperClass<T> {
    @Id
    protected String id;
    protected T defaultValue;
}

@Entity
public class ChildA extends MySuperClass<Boolean> {
    private String myCustomField;
}


@Entity
public class ChildB extends MySuperClass<Integer> {
    private Integer anotherCustomField;
}
```

And another entity with a relationship to the `MySuperClass` entity

```java
@Entity
class AnotherEntity {
    @Id 
    private String id;

    @OneToOne 
    private MySuperClass superClass;
}
```

(I omitted the lombok annotions)

These entities are not correctly generated.

With these annotions, the `defaultValue` SQL type is generated as a boolean type for each class. Of course, that's not what I want.

I tried to replace the `Entity` and `Inheritance` superclass annotations with `MappedSuperclass`: in this case, hibernate cannot build the relationship between `AnotherEntity` and `MySuperClass` as `MySuperClass` is not an entity.

I also tried to user the `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance strategy but the `defaultValue` field cannot be correctly typed in the single table (the boolean type is used by hibernate in this case). Ideally I want to use the `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy but I'm afraid that's not possible.

We are using PostgreSQL.

Comment: With TABLE_PER_CLASS is probably very difficult for hibernate to implement the query findAll(MySuperClass.class) because it would create a SQL UNION merging 2 columns with different types in the same column of the result set.

Comment: And SINGLE_TABLE would need to store twice the same property (default) because they don't have the same type. That will not happen.

Comment: Yes that's what I discovered. Do you have a suggestion to "implement" these entities with Hibernate ?

Comment: I don't there is possible way to modelize perfectly the generics in the database. At least, you will lose the foreign key constraints or lack of string typing